# How to pass onReceived data between classes Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

> I have 2 different class, first class Tracking.java and second class ReportingService.java. how to passing location address on ReportingService.java to Tracking.java?

```
 private void doLogout(){
    Log.i(TAG, "loginOnClick: ");
    //ReportingService rs = new ReportingService();
    //rs.sendUpdateLocation(boolean isUpdate, Location);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(NetHelper.getDomainAddress(this))
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ToyotaService toyotaService = retrofit.create(ToyotaService.class);

    // caller
    Call<ResponseBody> caller = toyotaService.logout("0,0",
            AppConfig.getUserName(this),
            "null");
    // async task
    caller.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.body().string());
            }catch (IOException e){}

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ", t);
        }
    });

    AppConfig.saveLoginStatus(this, AppConfig.LOGOUT);
    AppConfig.storeAccount(this, "", "");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

> This code for location address

```
 Call<ResponseBody> caller = toyotaService.logout("0,0",
            AppConfig.getUserName(this),
            "null");
```

> And this is class ReportingService.java location of code get longtitude, latitude and location address from googlemap

```
 private void sendUpdateLocation(boolean isUpdate, Location location) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged "+location.getLongitude());

    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    String street = "Unknown";
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (addresses != null) {
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
            String knowName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
            street = address + " " + city + " " + state + " " + country + " " + postalCode + " " + knowName;
            Log.i(TAG, "street "+street);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (isUpdate)
        NetHelper.report(this, AppConfig.getUserName(this), location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude(), street, new PostWebTask.HttpConnectionEvent() {
            @Override
            public void preEvent() {

            }

            @Override
            public void postEvent(String... result) {
                try {
                    int nextUpdate = NetHelper.getNextUpdateSchedule(result[0]); // in second
                    Log.i(TAG, "next is in " + nextUpdate + " seconds");
                    if (nextUpdate > 60) {
                        dismissNotification();
                        isRunning = false;
                    } else if (!isRunning){
                        showNotification();
                        isRunning = true;
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(location_updater, nextUpdate * 1000 /*millisecond*/);
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    Log.i(TAG, "postEvent error update");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    handler.postDelayed(location_updater, getResources().getInteger(R.integer.interval) * 1000 /*millisecond*/);
                }
            }
        });
    else
        NetHelper.logout(this, AppConfig.getUserName(this), location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude(), street, new PostWebTask.HttpConnectionEvent() {
            @Override
            public void preEvent() {

            }

            @Override
            public void postEvent(String... result) {
                Log.i(TAG, "postEvent logout "+result);
            }
        });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://github.com/square/otto) library and follow the provided example inside it.
Its for passing anything you wish to anywhere you wish.

Answer (score 0):

i think just using an interface will solve your problem.
pseudo code

ReportingException.java

add this

```
public interface myLocationListner{
onRecievedLocation(String location); 
} 

private myLocationListner mylocation;
```

//add below line where you get street address

```
mylocation.onRecievedLocation(street);
```

then  implement myLocationListner in Tracking.java 
there you go :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intent:

The intent will fire the 2nd Receiver and will pass the data into that

If BroadcastReceiver:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.2ndReceiverFilter");
intent.putExtra("key" , ); //put the data you want to pass on
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

If Service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();`
intent.putExtra("key" , value ); //put the data you want to pass on
startService( ReportingService.this , Tracking.class);
```

in Tracking.java, to retrieve the Data you passed on:
inside onReceive, put this code first

```
intent.getExtras().getString("key");//if int use getInt("key")
```